# computing a limit of a complicated form

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Suppose $f = e^{-1/t^2}$ on $t > 0$, what to show that $(\frac{f^{(n)}(t)}{(2n)!})^{\frac{1}{n}}$ tends to zero when $t$ is fixed. Intuitively the denominator grows faster than $n^{\frac{1}{2n}} n$ by stirling's formula, while the numerator will eventually be recursively producing terms that are less than $1$. So the limit must be zero. How to formalize this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider only $t > 0$. We show by induction that $f^{(n)}(t) = p_n(1/t) e^{-1/t^2}$ for all $n$, where $\{p_n\}$ is a sequence of polynomials starting with $p_0 = 1$. Assuming this holds for $n$, taking the derivative of each side gives
$$ f^{(n+1)}(t) = \left( -\frac{1}{t^2} p'_n(1/t) + \frac{2}{t^3} p_n(1/t) \right) e^{-1/t^2} \,, $$
and we can set
$$ p_{n+1}(x) = -x^2 p'_n(x) + 2x^3 p_n(x) \,. $$
Note that $p_n$ has degree $3n$. It is easy to see that if the coefficients of $p_n$ are bounded in absolute value by $M$, then the coefficients of $p_{n+1}$ are bounded in absolute value by $(3n+2)M \leq 3(n+1)M$. Thus the coefficients of $p_n$ are for all $n$ bounded by $3^n\cdot n!$.

The rest is easy: since $|p_n(t)| \leq (3n+1)(3^n\cdot n!)t^{3n} \leq 4^n\cdot n!\cdot t^{3n}$ for large $n$,
$$ \left| \frac{f^{(n)}(t)}{(2n)!} \right|^{1/n} \leq \frac{4t^3 \cdot e^{-1/nt^2}}{((2n)!/n!)^{1/n}} \leq \frac{4t^3}{n} \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0 \,. $$